# Ruby on Rails 4 - Cache Partials from Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on an app where certain pages take longer to load because of the views are a list of X to 1000 table rows. Each row has Y columns that take time to construct.

Right now, the first time the user hits the page with the table rows, it takes say N seconds. However, on refreshes, the page loads very quickly b/c of the cache.

I would like preload these partials and store it in my cache from a Rails model when the user logs in so if the user visits the page with the table rows, it will already be cached.

I have attempted to do this by calling a Sidekiq job when the user logins and cache the partial via a call below however even though I used the same cache key, it doesn't seem to be pulling from the same cache?

```html
view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})
view.render(...)
```

Any suggestions? I do know it is because when I call from the above, the fragment cache logic does not generate the digest. I ended up solving the issue by using Rails.cache fetch calls within a helper.